# Userscript to style Shadow DOM elements of arbitrary website

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom, userscripts

This is my userscript to change the color of visited links. It is assumed to be able to work with any website.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Change the color of visited links
// @description -
// @match       *://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

function style(css) {
  let head, style;
  head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  if (!head) return;
  style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.innerHTML = css.replace(/;/g, '!important;');
  head.appendChild(style);
}

function links(anylink, link, visited, hover, active) {
  style(`
    ${anylink} { outline: solid 1px; }
    ${link}    { color: blue;    }
    ${visited} { color: fuchsia; }
    ${hover}   { color: red;     }
    ${active}  { color: yellow;  }
  `);
}

links('a:any-link , a:any-link *',
      'a:link     , a:link     *',
      'a:visited  , a:visited  *',
      'a:hover    , a:hover    *',
      'a:active   , a:active   *'
     );
```

The problem is that on some websites some links belong to shadow DOM elements, and by this reason they are not affected by the script. How this can be fixed?

**temporary screenshot, see comments**

[image]

Comment: shadow DOM can not be styled by CSS unless exposing a some 'part' elements. You can still access shadowRoot for each element (but then that means you have to go through the whole dom to find all shadowRoots :))

Comment: "but then that means you have to go through the whole dom to find all shadowRoots" - Could you show how to do this? :)

Comment: I would recursivly loop on all dom element and check if they have a .shadowRoot entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the shadow DOM with `document.querySelector(selector).shadowRoot`

From there all you need to find the first `head` using `querySelectorAll` or default to the element itself, and inject the CSS there.

```js
// setup example
const host = document.querySelector("#host");
const shadow = host.attachShadow({
  mode: "open"
});
const span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "I'm in the shadow DOM <a href='#'>link</a>";
shadow.appendChild(span);


function addToHeadOrSelf(elem, css) {
  var head

  if (elem.getElementsByTagName) {
    head = elem.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  }

  if (elem.querySelectorAll) {
    head = elem.querySelectorAll('head')[0]
  }

  if (!head) {
    head = elem
  }

  style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.innerHTML = css.replace(/;/g, '!important;');
  head.appendChild(style);
}

function style(css) {
  addToHeadOrSelf(document, css)

  var elementsWithShadowRoot = findElementsWithShadowRoot()
  elementsWithShadowRoot.forEach(function(elem) {
    addToHeadOrSelf(elem.shadowRoot, css)
  })

}

function findElementsWithShadowRoot() {
  function hasShadowRoot(element) {
    return element.shadowRoot !== null;
  }

  function traverseTree(node) {
    if (hasShadowRoot(node)) {
      elementsWithShadowRoot.push(node);
    }

    const children = node.children || [];
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      traverseTree(children[i]);
    }
  }

  const elementsWithShadowRoot = [];
  traverseTree(document.body);
  return elementsWithShadowRoot;
}



function links(anylink, link, visited, hover, active) {
  style(`
    ${anylink} { outline: solid 1px; }
    ${link}    { color: blue;    }
    ${visited} { color: fuchsia; }
    ${hover}   { color: red;     }
    ${active}  { color: yellow;  }
  `);
}

links('a:any-link , a:any-link *',
  'a:link     , a:link     *',
  'a:visited  , a:visited  *',
  'a:hover    , a:hover    *',
  'a:active   , a:active   *'
);
```

```html
<div id="host"></div>

<span>I'm not in the shadow DOM <a href='#'>link</a></span>
<br />
```

Comment: ``document.head`` has been around for some time now

Comment: Itay, thanks a lot. Could you explain why it doesn't work here: https://archive.org/search?query=john+locke? I expect the works of John Locke to be styled, but they are not. I've added a screenshot to the question, temporary.

Comment: it's hard to debug like that. but maybe content is being written after script has run. or its dynmaic otherwise

Comment: @Yogi, could you edit the current answer to reflect this correction?

Comment: @Yogi This is pity that nowadays such simple tasks as adding custom styles became so complicated and so unreliable. It seems I would prefer to wait until there will be much simpler solutions to interact with shadow DOM using userscripts - and until then to not mess with shadow DOM at all.